# GLSL reading comparing and writing in a single operation?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, glsl, gpu

I have a variable that is stored in an SSBO that must be read by all shaders, compared against a value and conditionally set that value. To be more explicit, the following instruction should be done as an "atomic" operation:

```
SSBO[index] = SSBO[index] <= 0? atomicAdd(buffer_size) : SSBO[index];
```

To be more explicit, I have a tree whose memory must be allocated dynamically by each thread concurrently to keep the data compact (I cannot assume that the children are index of parent*2 and index of parent * 2 +1, because these would waste too much memory).

I know there is a way to "lock" the memory by setting it to -1 if it is 0, busy loop while the data is 0 or -1, and then execute the attomic adding.

Something like:

```
 while ((tree[node].children[child] <= 0) && (mrun > 0)){
            mrun--;
            //If the node wasn't allocated, allocate its memory (which also releases the lock)
            if( (atomicCompSwap( tree[node].children[child] , 0 , -1) == 0 ))
            {
                tree[node].children[child] = int(atomicAdd(t_index, 1));
            }
        }
```

That busy looping is a poor solution in my opinion. As it's inherently innefficient and if there is something built in into GLSL to emulate mutexes it would be better.

Comment: In general operations like `atomicCompSwap` can be applied to variables of [SSBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). But I think you want that `atomicAdd(buffer_size)` is only executed if `SSBO[index] <= 0`. So there should be 2 atomic operations, which depend on a conditions, performed as it would be one. May be I'm wrong, but I don't think that there exists a simple solution for this.